# HTML need a button that will change an output of another button

Tags: html, css, list, button, dropdown

I'm doing a little HTML project, I Have a Main CSS code the HTML that I'm stuck on,
I have (as you'll see in my code) a dropdown button which gives you several options, Now what I want is for when you click one of the options-
1. It shows the option in the main dropdown button (The text on it [Changing from "$4-$30 Aud" to whatever they pick])

2. and I want somehow for the "Add to cart" button to change to code that would redirect to what has been picked above it (the options mention above)

Anyway thanks for you help

**CSS:**

```
.button {
background-color: #ffffff;
border: none;
color: black;
padding: 15px 32px;
text-align: center;
text-decoration: none;
display: inline-block;
font-size: 16px;
margin: 1px 2px;
cursor: pointer;
}
ul {display: inline;
     list-style-type:none;
      text-decoration: none;}
.button:hover{
background-color:  #595959;
}
    .header {
        text-align: center;
        background-color: #2ac9b7;
        color: black;
        position: fixed;
        width: 100%;
        padding: 20px;
    }


html, body{
width:100%;
height:100%; background-color: #62666d; margin: 0px;
}


    h1 {
        font-weight:bold;
        color: #000000;
        font-size:42px;
    }


    .main {
        font-family: arial;
        margin: 0px;
    }

    .Content {
        top:0;
        bottom:0
        left:0;
        right:0;
        margin-top: 160px
    }
.dropbtn {
background-color: #4CAF50;
color: white;
padding: 16px;
font-size: 16px;
border: none;
cursor: pointer;
}

/* The container <div> - needed to position the dropdown content */
.dropdown {
position: relative;
display: inline-block;
}

/* Dropdown Content (Hidden by Default) */
.dropdown-content {
display: none;
position: absolute;
background-color: #f9f9f9;
min-width: 160px;
box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
z-index: 1;
}

/* Links inside the dropdown */
.dropdown-content a {
color: black;
padding: 12px 16px;
text-decoration: none;
display: block;
}

/* Change color of dropdown links on hover */
.dropdown-content a:hover {background-color: #f1f1f1}

/* Show the dropdown menu on hover */
.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
display: block;
}

/* Change the background color of the dropdown button when the dropdown             content is shown */
.dropdown:hover .dropbtn {
background-color: #3e8e41;
}
img
{
display: block;
margin: 0 auto;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<html>

<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="Masters_baby.css">
<div class="Main">
<div class="header">
    <div class="links">

        <ul><a href="index.html"><button class="button">Home</button></a>    </ul>
        <ul><a href="Shop.html"><button class="button">Shop</button></a></ul>
        <ul><a href="Art.html"><button class="button">Art</button></a></ul>
        <ul><a href="AboutMe.html"><button class="button">About Me</button></a></ul>
        <ul><a href="Support.html"><button class="button">Support</button> </a></ul>
        <ul><a href="Production.html"><button class="button">Production</button></a></ul>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
<IMG STYLE="position:absolute; TOP:23px; LEFT:20px; WIDTH:130px; HEIGHT:50px" SRC="Logo.png">
</head>

<body>
<IMG STYLE="TOP:180px; LEFT:30px; WIDTH:50px; HEIGHT:50px" SRC="Flame.png">
</body>
</div>
</div>  
<div class="parallax"></div>
 <div style="height:4950px; width:80%; margin:0 auto; background-color:#98eacc; margin-top: 44px">



   <div class="Products" style="padding-top: 50px;">

    <div class="∞ Frosted Kumquat" style= "width: 100%; height:9.1%;       width:80%; margin:0 auto; background-color:#fff; ">
    <p style="font-size: 25px">∞ Frosted Kumquat</p>
    <IMG STYLE="WIDTH:35%; HEIGHT:63%" SRC="candle.jpg"     >
    <table style="width: 100%;">
    <tbody>
    <tr>
    <td style="width: 80%;">A fresh citrusy smell that fills the room, Its is fairly stong washing out any unwanted smells or just lifting the room. Best for someone who doesnt like the smell of overly sweet but likes the fresh smell of fruit.</td>
    <td>
    <div class="dropdown"><button class="dropbtn">$4-$30 AUD</button>
    <div class="dropdown-content"><a href="#">Melts $4.00</a> <a   href="#">Tea light(6) $5.00</a> <a href="#">Candle in a Tin $14.00</a> <a     href="#">Specitally Candles $15.00-$30.00</a> <a href="#">Boxed candle   $22.00</a> <a href="#">Triplet pack of candles $28.00</a></div>   
    </div>
    </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td>
   <form target="paypal" action="https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr"   method="post">

<!-- Identify your business so that you can collect the payments. -->
<input type="hidden" name="business" value="kin@kinskards.com">

<!-- Specify a PayPal Shopping Cart Add to Cart button. -->
<input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_cart">
<input type="hidden" name="add" value="1">

<!-- Specify details about the item that buyers will purchase. -->
<input type="hidden" name="item_name" value="Birthday - Cake and Candle">
<input type="hidden" name="amount" value="3.95">
<input type="hidden" name="currency_code" value="USD">

<!-- Display the payment button. -->
<input type="image" name="submit"
src="Add2Cart.png"
alt="Add to Cart" STYLE="WIDTH:70%; HEIGHT:20%">
<img alt="" width="1" height="1"
src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/en_US/i/scr/pixel.gif">
    </td>
    </tr>
    </tbody>
    </table>    
    </div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</html>
```

Again Thanks for any help :)

Comment: For this functionality you would use JavaScript.  Start with some tutorials on the subject.  What you're essentially looking to do is respond to one element's `change` event, get the value from that element, and set the value/attribute/text/etc. of another element.

Comment: [Documentation](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onchange.asp). As I know you can't ask for something you don't know about. I recommend you to pick a tutorial over Html/css/js. And to learn the basic from it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, place all of your content in the `<body>`. Your head is where you link to stylesheets, load scripts and set meta-data etc. you don't want to have any content such as your header in the head.

You can achieve things like this with JavaScript. Let me give you an example.

Lets say we have the following HTML:

```
<select class="selector">
  <option value="10">10$</option>
  <option value="20" selected>20$</option>
  <option value="30">30$</option>
</select>

Selected plan: <span class="selected_plan">20$</span>
```

We want to change the content of the `span` with class *selected_plan* to the value selected in our `select` element.

First we need to create a new script (load your scripts at the bottom of your `body`).

`<script> // place your script here </script>`

or

`<script src="link_to_your_js_file.js"></script>`

Next we need to select our elements like so:

```
let selector = document.querySelector('.selector');
let selectedPlan = document.querySelector('.selected_plan');
```

Then we listen for when the `select` changes:

```
selector.addEventListener('change', function() {
    selectedPlan.innerHTML = selector.value + '$';
});
```

I created this JSFiddle for you so you can experiment with this particular example: https://jsfiddle.net/dgyyyoh8/1/

**EDIT:**

If I'm correct you want to change attributes as well. You can use the `setAttribute` method for this.

```
let link = document.querySelector('.element');
link.setAttribute('href', selected.value);
```

Take a look at this JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/dgyyyoh8/2/

1. Select our element
2. Create an event for when the selector changes
3. Set the innerHTMl of the link equal to 'Go to (text of the option)'
4. Set the href attribute equal to the selected options' value.

**EDIT:**

There are ways to change the appearance of the `select` element.

For example: https://codepen.io/ericrasch/pen/zjDBx

I'd suggest you also take a look at the CSS Framework [Bootstrap](https://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/). This framework contains a lot of classes you can work with to really take your styling to the next level.

Comment: This seems as close as I've seen about what I'm looking for so far, but how do I change it so the output are buttons that the Href changes or something

Comment: Also, I'm wondering if it can be anything else than <select>  because from my research i belive that you can't change the appearance of it.

Comment: @RedstoneMaina Take a look at my edits. I think I answered both of your questions.